# Filter rows based on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to keep the rows of dataframe df if the strings of "b" contain strings of "b2" from dataframe df2

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [100, 125, 300, 235], 'b': ["abc","ghf" "dfg", "hij"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[1, 2, 3, 4])

print(df)

     a    b
1  100  abc
2  125  ghf
3  300  dfg
4  235  hij
```

```py
d2 = {'a2': [10, 25, 30], 'b2': ["bc", "fg", "op"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2, index=[1, 2, 3])

print(df2)
   a2  b2
1  10  bc
2  25  fg
3  30  op
```

The output should look like this:

```py
     a    b
1  100  abc
2  300  dfg
```

I tried the following but it did not work.

```py
for majstring in df.b:
    for substring in set(df2.b2):
        if substring in majstring:
            pass
        else:
            df.drop(df.loc[df['b'] == majstring], inplace=True)
```

Comment: by index or anything to do with `a` or `a2`? Or is it just the rows of `df` is any `b2` in 'b'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mask = sum([df['b'].str.contains(v) for v in df2['b2']]).astype(bool)
filtered_df = df[mask]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered_df
     a    b
1  100  abc
3  300  dfg
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, this solution does not work, if the first dataframe df is longer than the second dataframe df2. In addition, the order of the values in df2 should not matter: I just want to check if any strings of b2 are in b and if so keep these rows. Sorry, for the confusion, I should have clarified this.

Comment: Will you please add a sample of a dataframe that doesn't work to the question? :)